# Why does Hogwarts always start on the 1st September?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

We all know that Hogwarts begins on the 1st September.

Is there a reason given that it's always the same date, leading to various days of the week? In 1991 and 1996 it was a Sunday!

I am a teacher in the UK and we tend to start around the 4th but it could be anything from 2nd to 6th.

Also, I know JK Rowling admits to being poor with maths, but I feel this is a deliberate choice and not a mistake. Is magic supposed to be involved?

Comment: seems fine to get a uniform start date never any confusion. the real question is in the book was there a year it started on saterday or friday, because almost every book talks about starting classes the next day after the feast and so they would be starting classes on a sunday or saterday haha.

Comment: Do we really know it starts on the same date every year?  How many books actually give the date?

Comment: There are 7 consecutive years in the series; that's enough to ensure that there is at least one year beginning on any given day of the week.

Comment: @b_jonas This was inspired by the question on the content of the Hogwarts letters. In that feed there are quotes where in all books (or almost all) the letter reminds the reader that it starts on Sept 1st.

Comment: I could have sworn this was a duplicate... I'm sure we've covered this before, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Himarm The Potterverse - no doubt due in no small part to JKR's dodgy maths - seems to have a special calendar where the first of September is always a Sunday, so the students are ready to start a full week of classes the very next day.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist a terrible oversight her fans will never forgive. she wont sell anymore books and go broke once this find is published. :D

Comment: @Anthony Grist Could magic be involved? She can't be THAT bad at maths!

Comment: Do Hogwarts students even get weekends off? I remember holidays/breaks being mentioned, but not weekends in specific.

Comment: @phantom42 Hogsmeade visits are only ever on weekends, and there are a couple of references to somebody being glad to reach the weekend, so I think they do.

Comment: Heck, I don't think any book other than PS gives the Hogwarts invitation letter, and I think no other book gives the date when Hogwarts starts either.  PS doesn't really count because when Rowling wrote that, she hadn't even fixed the year the events had happened, the year was fixed by the deathday parth in CS.

Comment: They do get week ends off: in OotP, Harry and Ron work on their homeworks and Hermione knits some hats. @MattGutting just no. Ever heard of [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisextile)? They travel on September the 1st, and start term on the 2d. Which lead to only one contradiction: OotP (95), when 09.01 was a Friday. Now IIRC, they started the term on a Monday. It is possible that JKR ellipsed the first week end... It should be checked.

Comment: @b_jonas again working from memory here, but I think the date is mentioned in PS, CoS and PoA. Well at least 3 anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong, *Prisoner of Azkaban* chapter 1 does show the letter with the date “September the first”.

Comment: And wow, even though *Chamber of Secrets* doesn't *quote* the main content of the letter, it does tell about Harry getting one and reading that the train starts on September the first, in chapter 4.

Comment: I think when I was a kid, primary school always started on September the 1st or the first weekday after that here, but I'm not completely sure, so I won't post an answer now.

Comment: @b_Jonas As I said in the question, schools always start AROUND the 1st, never before it and almost always after it. 2nd-6th usually.

Comment: The point is, school used to start exactly on September 1st when that day was a weekday, and it indeed was in 1992 (*Chamber*) and 1993 (*Prisoner*), and I think *Stone* can be discounted because Rowling didn't fix the year when she wrote it.

Comment: In reality, the first day back in September is rarely a Monday and almost never the first, even if the first is a week day.

Comment: I've just checked The Order of the Phoenix and the chapter after The Sorting Hat's New Song is Chapter 12: Professor Umbridge and they have lessons that day.

Comment: @MattGutting 7 consecutive years do **not** guarantee a year (or a September) starting with each day of the week. That only happens if none of the 7 years is a leap year.

Comment: I realized that a while after posting; I should have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 7):

I think except in some segments of the governing bodies of the witching world that witches and wizards are not exactly known as being well organized with fancy and shifting schedules. Just as J.K. Rowling has said she's not very good with the maths, I am will to bet it's just to make things simpler. No one needs to remember that this year we need to be at Kings cross on the 3rd, and next year it will be the 4th, unless of course it's a bank holiday. Which means the 6th.

Make it simple. Everyone...be at Kings cross on September 1st and that's the only date you really need to remember for when school starts.

Comment: I think this is probably the truth... but I want to hear JKR explain the part that doesn't really make sense! September 1st of his fifth year was a Friday, and they go to class the next day.

Comment: So how do you know that? Forgive me for asking but I am too lazy to figure it out myself.

Comment: I Googled Sept 1st 1995 and re-read the book. Chapter 12.

Comment: Do we know it was 1995? I don't remember years being referenced.

Comment: Yes, I forget which event makes it clear but it is canon that Harry's first year starts in Sept 1991 and therefore each book is its corresponding 1990s year. It's subtle but certain, and JKR is on record saying Harry was born in 1980 making him 11 in 1991, etc.

Comment: Well then it was probably the same over simplification that isn't important to the story really unless people like you and I dig too deeply into it

Comment: I won't say much more as I'm being prompted to move this to chat but it's interesting to me in particular because I am, and JKR used to be, a teacher in England. Perhaps she's deliberately simplified a complex thing but it's actually quite unrealistic when you're faced with it every year and you know she was too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's in order for the students. As the train, as we know, goes straight from King's Cross London to Hogsmeade (Obviously a fictional town, but placed in Scotland,) that's quite a journey. A train leaving from King's Cross going to Scotland takes about 8 and a half hours, so that takes us to about 5pm. We already know that they arrive around night, as each Start of Term assembly takes place at night, and in the Chamber of Secrets, Harry and Ron show up at night and attempt to enter the Great Hall, but are caught for being late.

I therefore assume that teaching itself begins on the 2nd of September, or even the 3rd; students need time to unpack and adjust back to school, especially if they are new.

Comment: Well, we know they don't start classes on the day of arrival. The first night is the assigning for new students, at the very least.

Comment: I think you'll find they always have classes the very next day.

Comment: I think the question's main point is that it's always the SAME calendar date, not which specific date it is.

Comment: That is what I'm wondering. And I think you'll find they get to work the very next day every time.

Comment: The train leaves at 11 AM, so if it’s eight and a half hours to get to Scotland (which is guesswork at best—we don’t know how far north in Scotland Hogwarts is, and we don’t know how fast trains go), they won’t be getting there till 7:30 at night. But that seems too early, as well. When they arrive in Hogsmeade, it’s described as being completely dark, and the sun doesn’t set until around 8:15 PM on 1 September in Scotland, so it’s probably more like a nine-and-a-half hour train ride. (And a very late dinner, particularly for 11-year-olds!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that with the ethnic cleansing theme of Harry Potter, that September 1 was chosen as the date the kids return to school because September 1 is also the date the Nazis invaded Poland, essentially starting WW2. Not that she is comparing Harry and Co to Nazis but Rowling is too smart to not have made that connection when choosing a significant date in a book series that leans heavily on racial purity and the execution of impure lineage.

Comment: This seems like pretty heavy speculation, can you provide any sources that suggest that was Rowling's thoughts. Given September 1st is around the time most UK schools would start again.